# Закрасить одинаковые значения в столбце DBGrid

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7

[image: Есть это]

[image: Нужно получить это]

```
procedure TForm10.DBGrid2DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var id:integer;
s:string;
begin
 IF (DataCol=0) then
 Begin
      if(DBGrid2.Columns[0].Field.AsString=old)then
      Begin
           DBGrid2.Canvas.Font.Color:=clWindow;
           DBGrid2.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
      End;
      old:=DBGrid2.Columns[0].Field.AsString;//old-предыдущий символ
 End;
end;
```

Данный код работает только при запуске, но когда меняю положение курсора он либо закрашивает то что не нужно, либо не закрашивает ячейку вообще. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте в конце процедуры TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect,DataCol,Column,State);